# How to query against dbo.AspNetUserLogins table (IdentityUserLogin entity)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using the standard MVC template with the identity provider in VS 2013.

By extending `ApplicationUser:IdentityUser`, I am able to access the table `AspNetUsers` using `ApplicationDbContext`.

I now want to query the data in another table, `AspNetUserLogins`.  How do I reference it without having to create a new database context and a new Entity Data Model to represent this existing table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding entity for `dbo.AspNetUserLogins` table is `IdentityUserLogin` class. So we just need to declare an appropriate `IDbSet<IdentityUserLogin>` or `DbSet<IdentityUserLogin>` property in the `ApplicationDbContext` class as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ...
    public IDbSet<IdentityUserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

and then query it as usually:

```
using (var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var userLogins = dbContext.UserLogins.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will this approach "disturb" the existing code first approach the framework is using?

Comment: @OldGeezer, nope, it won't. As usually it just gives you a capability to query against AspNetUserLogins table. Any declaration of DbSet or IDbSet property in DbContext class does not affect any configurations, if the DbContext already "knows" about the entity. In our example it does know, because there are explicit configurations for this entity in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for anyone looking to do this with asp .Net Core:

Add user manager to your controller constructor that you can access below by DI.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var hello = await _userManager.GetLoginsAsync(user);
```